# change button in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragmentactivity

I have two buttons in a fragment that I want when clicking on the first button this button change to white color and the second button change to black and if click on the second button, second button change to white color and firs button change to black color
this is my code in mainActivity:

```
public void buttonOne(View view) {
    Button1 = findViewById(R.id.tg_btn2);
    Button2 = findViewById(R.id.tg_btn1);
    //If the Button is off
    if (!btnOneOn) {

        Button2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_blue_grey_900));
        Button1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor((R.color.md_white_1000)));
        Button1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_blue_grey_100));
        Button2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_black_1000));
        btnTwoOn = false;
        btnOneOn = true;
        Log.i("Salam",btnOneOn.toString());
    }
    //If it is is clicked while on
    else {
        btnTwoOn = false;
        Button2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor((R.color.md_blue_grey_900)));
    }
}

public void buttonTwo(View view) {
    Button2 = findViewById(R.id.tg_btn2);
    Button1 = findViewById(R.id.tg_btn1);
    //If the Button is off
    if (!btnTwoOn) {

        Button1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_blue_grey_900));
        Button2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor((R.color.md_white_1000)));
        btnOneOn = false;
        btnTwoOn = true;
    }
    //If it is is clicked while on
    else {
        btnOneOn = false;
        Button1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor((R.color.md_blue_grey_900)));
    }
```

but it doesn't work correctly
what is your suggestion?

Comment: What exactly does it do when you try this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution   Activity :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main2, container, false);

    final Button button1 = v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    final Button button2 = v.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gray);
            button2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
        }
    });

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
            button2.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gray);

        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

activity_main2.xml :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button1"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button2"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is in this fragment of code

```
setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.md_blue_grey_900))
```

Try like this

```
setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.md_blue_grey_900))
```

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is that you put

```
 Button1 = findViewById(R.id.tg_btn2);
Button2 = findViewById(R.id.tg_btn1);
```

in the buttonOne and buttonTwo methods and it is like that you make new buttons and work on them 
put this two line out and put the in onStart method like this

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Button1 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tg_btn2);
    Button2 = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tg_btn1);
}
```

and remove them from buttonOne and buttonTwo OnClick

i hope it solve your problem and be helpful (: